# How to parse fields out of a text file and write them to another file

Tags: scripting, sed, awk

I have executed a database command and have generated an output file of the results.
Each field name starts with `dbt_xxxxxx`
Each field value is the value after the equal sign.
how can I parse the file and write out a new file 
where the field name is in on column and the value is another column
and create a header for the file

```
dbt_dbid=4   dbt_stat=0x0 (0x0000)
dbt_extstat=0x0 (0x0000)
dbt_stat2=0x0 (0x0000)
dbt_stat3=0x20000 (0x00020000 (DBT3_SYSPARTITIONS_EXISTS))
dbt_stat4=0x0 (0x00000000)
dbt_runstat=0x0(0x0000)
dbt_state=0x2(0x0002 (DBST_ACTIVE))   dbt_keep=0  dbt_hdeskeep=0
dbt_next=0x000000002197DE80   dbt_systask_keep=0 dbt_detachxact_keep 0
    dbt_dcompver_default=1
dbt_lock=0  dbt_dbaid=1
dbt_verstimestamp= May 15 2012  3:37PM   dbt_dbname=TestDB
dbt_logrows=0
dbt_lastlogbp=0x0000000000000000
dbt_logsema=000000000099EE10 
dbt_nextseq=11  dbt_oldseq=11
dbt_dbinfobuf.dbi_logvers=7
dbt_dbinfobuf.dbi_upgdvers=35 ... .dbi_upgd_minor=1720
dbt_dbinfobuf.dbi_dbinfovers=5
dbt_dbinfobuf.dbi_sarg_vers=2  dbt_threshstat=0x0
dbt_thresholds=0x00000000219873B8  dbt_thresh_spin=0x000000002011E300
dbt_maxthresh=256
thc_segment   2 thc_level   664 thc_status 0xf  <-- last chance threshold
dbt_nextid=560001995 dbt_nextidstat=0x0
dbt_dflinfo=0x0000000000000000  dbt_dflstat=0x0
dbt_dumpthreadlock=0
dbt_dbts=0x0000 0x00001492   dbt_xdesqueue   next=0x0000000021986C20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
echo -e "Name\tValue" \
    | cat input.txt - \
    | sed -e 's/dbt_/\ndbt_/g;s/=/\t/g' \
          -e 's/^[[:space:]]//;s/[[:space:]]$//;/^$/d'
```

Now, this leaves the "thc_segment" line alone, and makes the last line `dbt_xdesqueue   next    0x0000000021986C20`. If you want something else, you'll have to specify it.

Comment: Caption won't appear that way, cause `cat` will eat `echo` output and do not printout it again. You can use `sed` for printing caption. Just add to it `-e '1i Name\tValue'`. Also seems field name doesn't start only with dbt_. Try to replace like this: `s/\([a-z]\+\)_/\n\1_/g`

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  printf "%s\t%s\n" Name Value
  grep -Po 'dbt_.+?=.*?(?=dbt_|$)' input_file | tr = '\t'
} > output_file
```